# Simple way to choose a file

Tags: java, filepath, joptionpane, jfilechooser

Is there some simple way to choose a file path in Java? I've been searching around, and `JFileChooser` keeps coming up, but that's already too excessive for what I want now, as it seems to require making a whole GUI just for that. I'll do it if need be, but is there a simpler way to get the file path?

I'm wondering if there's something like a `JOptionPane` dialog box to search for the file path.

Comment: the file chooser is actually very easy to implement. You don't need to build a whole UI around it. You just have to open it, get the file selected by the user, and then pass it on to your methods. You can even have validation within the panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have no surrounding UI, you can simply use this (based on the Answer from [Valentin Montmirail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894476/1339257))

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int returnValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog( null );

    switch ( returnValue )
    {
    case JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION:
        System.out.println( "chosen file: " + fileChooser.getSelectedFile() );
        break;
    case JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION:
        System.out.println( "canceled" );
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. What threw me was the 'null' in the showOpenDialog. None of the other online tutorials said that you could put in a null if you don't have a surrounding UI.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simpliest way to choose a file path in Java :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //Handle open button action.
    if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(YourClass.this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            //This is where a real application would open the file.
            log.append("Opening: " + file.getName() + "." + newline);
        } else {
            log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
   } ...
}
```

You can plug this actionPerformed to a button for example, and that's it. Your button will open a GUI to select a file, and if the user select the file `JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION`, then you can perform the action that you want (here only logging what was opened)

See the oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html) if you want to do something else (not binding a button ?) or something more complex (filter for some extensions only ? ...)

Answer (score 0):

JFileChooser is not that complicated if you only need to choose a file.

```
public class TestFileChooser extends JFrame {
    public void showFileChooser() {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println("Selected file: " + selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new TestFileChooser().showFileChooser();
    }
}
```